# Ajax request to send CURL request

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am submitting the data from a from via Ajax and it needs to make a curl request to an endpoint. I am not getting any errors but when I check the data in the endpoint it isn't there. If I submit the form just using normal html then it works. So, something is incorrect with my CURL code I would imagine.

```
<?php

  $response = [];
  $message = '';

   $data = [
        'first_name'      => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'       => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'           => $_POST['email'],
];


$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL        => 'https://someEndpoint.com?encoding=UTF-8',
    CURLOPT_POST       => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
];


$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);


$results = curl_exec($curl);


curl_close($curl);

$response['success'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Thank you, your request has been submitted.';

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1` be `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1`?

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks. That didn't resolve the issue though

Comment: The post data should also be posted like `first_name=foo&last_name=bar` and not as an array. Try: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)`

Comment: Dude, you are a legend! Please make that your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently passing the post fields as an array. However, cURL expects it to be passed as a string in this format:

```
first_name=foo&last_name=bar&...
```

It's just like a query string.

We can use [http_build_query()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to convert the array to the above format:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
```